# How do I make jquery dropped element droppable and inherit original properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good afternoon! I'm primarily a php programmer and am not at all proficient with javascript or jquery and am really hoping someone can help me out. I'm trying to learn on the fly with a little drag and drop schedule project I'm building for work but I feel like my lack of knowledge is causing me to hack this all together. I essentially have an unordered list displayed for each job as well as one for employees, one for trucks, and one for equipment. The goal is to have the employees working on the job to be dropped onto the job and become droppable for the truck they're driving to the job, or equipment they're using on the job. The trouble I'm having, and forgive me for the lack of proper terminology, is that when the employee is dropped on the job it's not a "real" element. When I try to delete it or drop a truck onto the employee (programmatically haha), it fails because the id (or "data-empID" in this case) is undefined and doesn't get passed to my php script. However, if I refresh the page and hit delete it works fine because the data originated on the page load. How do I make it so when an element gets dropped, it acts as though it was loaded with the rest of the page so I can delete it from a job, make a copy of it to put on more than one job, or move it to another job?

Here's a screenshot:
[image: Here's a screenshot]

Here's the bit of code i'm working on:

```
$(".source li").draggable({ 
    helper: "original",
    revert: "invalid",
    scroll: true,
    start: function( event, ui ) {
        theID = $(this).prop("id");
        $(this).addClass("used_source");
    },
    end: function( event, ui){
        $(this).addClass("targeted");
    }
});

$(".target").droppable({
    addClasses: false,
    activeClass: "listActive",
    accept: ".employeeTarget",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var ths = $(this);
        var src = $(this).closest("ul").prop("id");
        var emp = ui.draggable.attr("data-empID");
        var jobDate = getParameterByName("d");
        $('[data-empID="'+emp+'"]').draggable({ helper:"clone" });

        $.ajax ({
            url: "assets/php/data.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: {type:'employee', job: src, employee: emp, date: jobDate},
            success: function(data){ 
                console.log(data);
                if(data == 'failed'){
                    $(ui.helper).remove();        
                    alert("Employee is already listed on this job.");
                }else{
                    var link = $("<a href='#' class='dismiss'>x</a>");
                    var list = $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text());
                    $(ths).find(".placeholder").remove();    
                    $(ui.helper).remove();
                    $(list).append(link);
                    $(list).appendTo(ths);
                    $(this).find('ul').append(ui.draggable);
                    $('[data-empID="'+emp+'"]').addClass(".employeeTarget");
                    $(".employeeTarget").draggable({ 
                        helper: "original",
                        revert: "invalid",
                        scroll: true,
                        start: function( event, ui ) {
                            theID = $(this).prop("id");
                            $(this).addClass("used_source");
                        },
                        end: function( event, ui){
                            $(this).addClass("targeted");
                        }
                   });
                }
             },
             error: function(req, err){ console.log(err); alert(data);}
         });
      }
}).on("click", ".dismiss", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var em = $(this).parent().attr("data-empID");
    var par = $(this).parent().text();
    var emName = $(this).parent().text();
    var empName = emName.slice(0,-1);
    var jb = $(this).closest("ul").prop("id");
    var jobDate = getParameterByName("d");
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "assets/php/remove.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {type: 'employee', job: jb, employee: em, date: jobDate},
        success: function(data){ 
            console.log(data);
            if(data == 'FAILED!'){      
                alert("Employee has not been removed.");
            }else if(data == 'RESET!'){
                console.log(em);
                $(".source").append('<li class="list-group-item employeeTarget" id="" data-empID="' + em + '">' + empName + '</li>');
                $('[data-empID="'+em+'"]').draggable();
                $('[data-empID="'+em+'"]').addClass(".source");

            }
        },
        error: function(req, err){ console.log(err); alert(data);}
    });
});
```

My lists look like this:

```
<ul>';
    <li class="list-group-item employeeTarget" data-empID="1">Employee One</li>
    <li class="list-group-item employeeTarget" data-empID="1">Employee Two</li>
    <li class="list-group-item employeeTarget" data-empID="1">Employee Three</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li class="list-group-item vehicle" data-eqID="0" data-vID="50">Truck 50</li>
<li class="list-group-item vehicle" data-eqID="0" data-vID="103">Truck 103</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="list-group-item vehicle" data-vID="0" data- eqID="32">Excavator</li>
    <li class="list-group-item vehicle" data-vID="0" data- eqID="24">Backhoe</li>
</ul>
```

As I mentioned earlier, i'm not very proficient with javascript or jquery and i'm sure that some of you can write that code in less then half the lines I did. I'm also sure that there's a much more efficient way to accomplish this. Basically when an employee gets added to the job, an "X" gets appended to the name to remove the employee if needed. When the page loads, if there is no employees listed there is a placeholder node that gets removed when an employee gets added. I also need to make copies of the employees if they're on multiple jobs that day by dragging the employee again to another job but I can figure that out later.

I didn't bother with the "connectwith" option yet because I'm familiar with that  and I'm trying to get this to work first before moving forward with that. I've searched a lot for a work around for this but haven't been successful. I'm not sure if there's a way to have the dropped elements inherit properties as if it was there when the page loads, or if i'm going about this all wrong. Any help is much appreciated even if this is a "duplicate" post and someone can point me toward the correct answer. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: On drop, a fresh `<li>` element is appended. The only characteristics given to that `<li>` are some innerText and a `.dismiss` button. The `.dismiss` button's (delegated) click handler expects to read `.attr('data-empID')` from the button's parent element - an `<li>` that doesn't have that attribute.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 YOU'RE A GENIUS! I can't believe I missed that. I was so sidetracked by it not working that I didn't even check the basics. Thank you for the help. Now I just have to make the dropped employee droppable and finish it up. That was such a big help! Thanks again

Comment: If I'm correct in understanding that you want to leave the original employee behind in the employees list, then you would find it simpler to drag/drop a clone rather than creating a fresh `<li>` yourself ... `$(".source li").draggable({
 'helper': 'clone',
 ...
});`. You still need to append a dismiss button, but I think I'm right in saying that the clone will inherit draggability from the original.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Yes and no. At first I want to drag the original employee from the list so at a quick glance we know who's left to schedule. From that point, the idea is to then drag clones of that employee to be able to schedule them on multiple jobs that day. The clones will come only from the employee that has previously been dropped on a job.

Comment: Ah, there's more to it than I realised.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Yea, I didn't want to post the whole code because that part shouldn't be too difficult. I also didn't want to be greedy and ask the community to write the code for me :) Thanks for the help! It's much appreciated

Comment: George, good luck with it.